# How to achieve expected output through Android bitmap?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, bitmap

I am using `Bitmap` transformation to add `Image`and `Text` on another image. As per my code I am getting very blurred image:

[image]

What I am expecting is this:

[image]

My `Bitmap` transformation code as follow:

```
 Bitmap resultBitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true);
 Bitmap bitmapImage = 
 BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_heart);
 bitmapImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapImage, 90, 90, true);

 Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
 Paint paint = new Paint();
 paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
 paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
 Paint rectPaint = new Paint();
 rectPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
 rectPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
 rectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
 rectPaint.setTextSize(40);
 rectPaint.setAlpha(400);
 paint.setAlpha(150);
 canvas.drawText("$250", 20, 400, rectPaint);
 canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapImage, 550, 55, null);
 canvas.drawRect(0, 350, 140, 420, paint);

 bitmap.recycle();
 return resultBitmap;
```

What I am doing wrong here? I tried every possible but it is getting always fade :( Can I achieve it by putting black transparent image in a background then add text on it or I can also achieve it by `Bitmap` ?

Comment: Move the line canvas.drawText next after canvas.drawRect and see whether it helps you.

Comment: try reducing your value for `setalpha()` make it as below `rectPaint.setAlpha(40);` instead of `rectPaint.setAlpha(400);` 400 seems to be a larger value.